# Error while loading XML data into hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

Im trying to load an XML file into my hive table. Below is my hive table query.

```
CREATE TABLE MYDATA(NAME STRING, AGE INT, SEX STRING)
   ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
   WITH SERDEPROPERTIES(
   "column.xpath.NAME"="/TAG/NAME/text()",
   "column.xpath.AGE"="/TAG/AGE/int()",
   "column.xpath.SEX"="/TAG/SEX/text()")
   STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
   OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
   LOCATION '/home/sid/hivexmltab'
   TBLPROPERTIES("xmlinput.start"="<TAG","xmlinput.end"="</TAG>");
```

My input file is in the below format:

```
<TAG>
 <NAME>ABCD</NAME><AGE>25</AGE><SEX>male</SEX>
 <NAME>EFGH</NAME><AGE>23</AGE><SEX>female</SEX>
</TAG>
```

I want to see the output like below:

```
ABCD,25,male
EFGH,23,female
```

But Im getting output like below:

```
<string>ABCDEFGH</string>   NULL    <string>malefemale</string>
```

Im using the jar file: hivexmlserde-1.0.5.3.jar for Xml SerDe

Can anyone tell me what is the error Im making here ?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one bad XML structure...
Any combination of `<NAME>...</NAME><AGE>...</AGE><SEX>...</SEX>` should have been wrapped by an additional tag.

---

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE MYDATA
(
    NAME    array<string>
   ,AGE     array<int>
   ,SEX     array<string>    
)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlSerDe'
    WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
    (
        "column.xpath.NAME" = "TAG/NAME/text()"
       ,"column.xpath.AGE"  = "TAG/AGE/text()"
       ,"column.xpath.SEX"  = "TAG/SEX/text()"
    )
    STORED AS 
    INPUTFORMAT     'com.ibm.spss.hive.serde2.xml.XmlInputFormat'
    OUTPUTFORMAT    'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.IgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION        '/home/sid/hivexmltab'
    TBLPROPERTIES
    (
        "xmlinput.start" = "<TAG"
       ,"xmlinput.end"   = "</TAG>"
    )
;
```

---

```
select * from MYDATA
;
```

---

```
+-----------------+------------+-------------------+
|     a.name      | mydata.age |    mydata.sex     |
+-----------------+------------+-------------------+
| ["ABCD","EFGH"] | [25,23]    | ["male","female"] |
+-----------------+------------+-------------------+
```

---

```
select  NAME[pe.n]  as name
       ,AGE [pe.n]  as age
       ,SEX [pe.n]  as sex

from    MYDATA m
        lateral view posexplode (m.NAME) pe as n,x
;
```

---

```
+------+-----+--------+
| name | age |  sex   |
+------+-----+--------+
| ABCD |  25 | male   |
| EFGH |  23 | female |
+------+-----+--------+
```

Comment: Its working. Really helped a lot in constructing proper table structure for loading xml files.

Answer (score 1):

use text() everywhere ,modify age part as:

```
   "column.xpath.AGE"="/TAG/AGE/text()"
```

You can alter datatype later in hive table

Remove the location part from CREATE TABLE :

```
LOCATION '/home/sid/hivexmltab'
```

and rather use LOAD command to load all your data after creating your table

```
load data local inpath '/home/sid/hivexmltab/XMLfile.xml' overwrite into table MYDATA;
```